# Why does Umbraco WYSIWYG place forward slash in front of a tag link?

Tags: c#, tinymce, wysiwyg, umbraco

I am using the Umbraco WYSIWYG datatype, and I noticed when using the HTML window to input HTML, that an A tag

```
<a href="http://www.someurl.com">link</a>
```

Will end up being:

```
<a href="/http.....>link</a>
```

This also happens if the link is just www.something.com and not Http://.  It will also start with a (/).

As a bonus side affect, if it does have http:// in the link, the forward slash will change this link from

```
http://
```

to

```
/http:/     (single forward slash like its a path)
```

The WYSIWYG is the TinyMCE WYSIWYG.  Why does it do this, and what can I do to change it?

Comment: I'm just guessing here having never used the software but it looks to me like it is trying to make sure you never link to external sites and assuming that all links you provide are absolute urls in the site (thus prepending the `/` and "normalizing" the `//`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change the *TinyMCE* config to change this behavior. In the file  `config/tinyMceConfig.config`, add this to the `<customConfig>` section at the end of the file:

```
<config key="relative_urls">true</config>
```

Read about [relative_urls at tinymce site](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3arelative_urls).